# ng-click open all the input. Can ng-directive helpful?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

When "reply" link is clicked it open all the input tags associated with ng-show. How can I change it to just open the adjacent input tag of "reply" link? Example as in Facebook when a reply is clicked it open only the adjacent input tag. The number of blockquote is infinite as data is going to come from backend. so how can we dynamically manage the blockquote?

```js
angular.module("myDiscuss", [])
  .controller("TabController", function() {
    this.tab = 0;
    this.subTab = 0;
    this.like = 0;
    this.selectLike = function(setTab) {
      this.like = setTab;
    };
    this.selectTab = function(setTab) {
      this.tab = setTab;
    };
    this.selectSubTab = function(setTab) {
      this.subTab = setTab;
    };
    this.isSelected = (function(checkTab) {
      return this.tab === checkTab;
    });
    this.isSelectedSub = (function(checkTab) {
      return this.subTab === checkTab;
    });
    this.isSelectedLike = (function(checkTab) {
      return this.like === checkTab;
    });

  });
```

```html
<div class="thumbnail" style="border-radius: 0px;" ng-controller="TabController as tabs">
  <ul class="nav nav-pills">
    <li role="presentation" ng-class="{ active:like === 1 }">
      <a href ng-click="tabs.selectLike(1)" class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up">Helpful</a>
    </li>
    <li ng-class="{ active:tab === 2 }">
      <a href ng-click="tabs.selectTab(2)" class="glyphicon">Comment</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <div class="panel" ng-show="tabs.isSelected(2)">
    <blockquote>
      <img src="../images/cover.jpg" class="img-reponsive pull-left">
      <div style="overflow: hidden;">
        <h4>Name</h4>
        <p>.......</p>
      </div>
      <div ng-show="tabs.isSelectedSub(3)">
        <small>....</small>
      </div>
      <ul class="nav nav-pills">
        <li ng-class="{ active:subTab === 3 }">
          <a href ng-click="tabs.selectSubTab(3)" class="glyphicon ">Helpful</a>
        </li>
        <li ng-class="{ active:subTab === 4}">
          <a href ng-click="tabs.selectSubTab(4)" class="glyphicon">Reply</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <div style="overflow:hidden" ng-show="tabs.isSelectedSub(4)">
        <img src="../images/cover.jpg" class="img-reponsive pull-left">
        <input class="col-sm-8 col-md-8 col-lg-11" type="text">
      </div>
    </blockquote>
    <blockquote>
      <img src="../images/cover.jpg" class="img-reponsive pull-left">
      <div style="overflow: hidden;">
        <h4>Name</h4>
        <p>.......</p>
      </div>
      <div ng-show="tabs.isSelectedSub(3)">
        <small>....</small>
      </div>
      <ul class="nav nav-pills">
        <li ng-class="{ active:subTab === 3 }">
          <a href ng-click="tabs.selectSubTab(3)" class="glyphicon ">Helpful</a>
        </li>
        <li ng-class="{ active:subTab === 4}">
          <a href ng-click="tabs.selectSubTab(4)" class="glyphicon">Reply</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <div style="overflow:hidden" ng-show="tabs.isSelectedSub(4)">
        <img src="../images/cover.jpg" class="img-reponsive pull-left">
        <input class="col-sm-8 col-md-8 col-lg-11" type="text">
      </div>
    </blockquote>
  </div>
```

Image when "reply" link is clicked:

[image: Image when "reply" link is clicked]

Answer (score 0):

This problem is screaming for a directive for two reasons.  1) Reusable component 2) Provide isolate scopes which will help contain each of those replies.  The isolate scopes will make it much easier to keep each component self-contained.

Comment: If need help creating this directive, I would suggest updating the question to see if someone can help with their time.